# Why is current_page? returning false when I am passing it my current path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the current_page? method in a helper file like this:

```
if current_page?("users/#{user.id}/posts") || current_page?("users/#{user.id}")
```

And it is false when my path is the same as the arguments passed to the second current_page? call

Here is the url of my current page:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/3
```

user.id == 3 right now

I have the better-errors debugger open, and here is the result of some current_page? calls:

```
current_page?(controller: "users") == false


current_page?(action: "show") == true

current_page?("users/3") == false

current_page? "http://localhost:3000/users/3" == true
```

Why is the current_page? method failing for my relative path?

I don't want to prepend it with the localhost:3000 because then the method call would only be true in development.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting relative paths, like this:

```
 if current_page?("/users/#{user.id}/posts") || current_page?("/users/#{user.id}"
```